# Use Oracle's DBMS_SESSION.set_context in Entity Framework Core

Tags: oracle, .net-core, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I have the need to show on my .net core program an Oracle view that in the database has some columns filtered by

```
... WHERE dictionary.LANGUAGE = SYS_CONTEXT ('CLIENTCONTEXT', 'LANGUAGE');
```

Obviously fetching the data directly on the application makes those columns return a null value.

I would need to implement something like this

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(String.Format("BEGIN DBMS_SESSION.SET_CONTEXT('CLIENTCONTEXT', 'LANGUAGE', '{0}'); END;", ActualLanguage), ORACLEconn as OracleConnection);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

How would I go about implementing the code using Entity Framework Core? Would I need to call it once on the model creation or every time I create a new `DbContext`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a DbContext constructor that's only used when you want the session context set, you can force the connection open, and it will remain open until your DbContext is disposed.  eg

```
public Db(DbContextOptions opts) : base(opts)
{
    this.Database.OpenConnection();
    this.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("BEGIN DBMS_SESSION.SET_CONTEXT('CLIENTCONTEXT', 'LANGUAGE', 'whatever'); END;");
}
```

Or you can use an [Interceptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors) to run the command every time a connection is opened.